# How can I match a GameObject to its resource ID in the .Unity scene file

Tags: unity-game-engine

These are the file contents for a Unity scene

```
--- !u!1 &341095427
GameObject:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_PrefabParentObject: {fileID: 143402, guid: e58d4c3907fdc484faf3ab7001288374, type: 2}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 0}
  serializedVersion: 4
  m_Component:
  - 4: {fileID: 341095443}
  m_Layer: 8
  m_Name: Main Camera
  m_TagString: MainCamera
  m_Icon: {fileID: 0}
  m_NavMeshLayer: 0
  m_StaticEditorFlags: 0
  m_IsActive: 1
```

The serialized resource Id for this object is on the first line (**341095427**). My script is an editor invoked from a Unity menu. I am iterating through all of the GameObjects in the currently active scene. Is there a way to get the above Id for a GameObject? Unfortunately GetInstanceID() returns a different value.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is the Asset Local Id. This id is resolved by Unity3d Remapper and its not accesible class and there no api to get this.
GetInstanceId got this resolved ID cached int, but how you tell this id is not ever the same ID
Check this [link](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/assets-objects-and-serialization) for a extended help of how this work

You can use your own UID and include this in your object:

`public string Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();`